# How manage different countries/languages in Predictive Intelligence Catalog

Tags: marketing-cloud, einstein-recommendations

Do you have any suggestions regarding the implementation of Predictive Intelligence's Catalog and specifically how manage fields as ProductDescription, ProductLink,RegularPrice, etc. for different countries/languages?
What custom fields can be added in the catalog in order to show the correct locale assigned to the customer in the web recommendations?

I've seen that you can enable locale option when you are defining the catalog feed. This gives you the possibility to add custom fields (e.g. locale_en-GB_ProductLink, locale_fr-FR_ProductName).
Are there other ways to handle this implementation?

Comment: Hey Robert, You're on the lines I'd go down with the locale specific attributes in the catalog. I'd be interested in something better, too.

Answer (score 0):

I would try a different approach.

Since you seem to handle multiple languages on your website, i believe that you also have a product information system or some other system behind/on your website where all the informations are stored in multiple languages.

I would just deliver a unique-id towards the backend of the shop and let it do the rest of the stuff (styling, enrichment of the data etc. in the right language).

Hope that helps.

Comment: Yes, it could be a possible solution, because the ecommerce has all the products but it works only for web recommendations. Indeed, we are not able to handle the requirement in the email recs.

Comment: For email recommendations that are based on web recommendations and should be locale specific, you have to define a product catalog with all those locale fields. Then you can use those locale variables with an attachment of the recommendation-link like ?locale=de-de or something like that. (Look up the syntax on help pages of Salesforce)